# "For example" and "such as"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, lists

when we use "for example" or "such as" in writing, do we have to use a specific tense? 
All websites talk about the punctuation,but want to know about the suitable tense or grammar.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence, please?  These phrases usually introduce a string of nouns.

Comment: There are many ways to reduce car accidents, such as not to exceed the speed limits. Is it correct?

Comment: Ah, use the gerund form, not the infinitive.  "such as not exceeding the speed limits"

Comment: what about "for example" ?

Comment: The same.  'For example' & 'such as' are interchangeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When what you are listing is a verb or a verbal phrase, use the *gerund* form.

> We all have many home-maintenance tasks, such as washing our clothes, cleaning the kitchen, and taking out the garbage.